# Querying for multiple vertex properties using PropertyValue does not work

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks, properties

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and fixed in 12.0**

---

The syntax variant `PropertyValue[...,{prop1, prop2}]` of `PropertyValue` does not evaluate in Mathematica 11.2 (on macOS).

---

**Example:**

```
g = Graph[{
    Property[1, {"prop1" -> 1, "prop2" -> "one"}], 
    Property[2, {"prop1" -> 2, "prop2" -> "two"}], 
    Property[3, {"prop1" -> 3, "prop2" -> "three"}]}, 
   {1 <-> 2,2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}]
```

Try:

```
PropertyValue[{g, 1}, {"prop1", "prop2"}]
PropertyValue[{g, 1}, "prop1"]
PropertyValue[{g, 1}, "prop2"]
```

The first one does not evaluate.

According to the documentation,

[image]

Comment: I believe there's a typo in the input vertex list.  The bug is independent of the duplicate vertex though